# Is the character from Far cry 2 the person who shot Longinus (Far Cry 4) in the head?

Tags: far-cry-4, far-cry-2

[Longinus](http://farcry.wikia.com/wiki/Longinus) is a character from FarCry 4 who is a 'converted' warlord that got shot in the head and then nurtured by [Priest Maliya](http://farcry.wikia.com/wiki/Father_Maliya), who comes from the Far Cry 2 story.

[image: Screenshot showing Longinus]

Is there evidence to support that the character from Far Cry 2 is the person who shot Longinus in the head?

Comment: @Timelord64 Hence why there's no accepted answer. :)

Comment: So you can forsee the future that there will be no answer from an expert?

Comment: @Timelord64 done.

Answer (score 5):

That's what I'm thinking. They've subtly incorporated a few things from FC2 into FC4 like controlling how long you sleep, the tracker that Longinus gives you. When he said he was a warlord I immediately flashed back to my adventures in Africa. That game was all about blood/conflict diamonds and warring factions. I think it's very possible that our mercenary from FC2 was the one who squeezed that trigger, if not him then he had something to do with it. I always love to see small things like this that have connections to previous games that not everyone may catch.

Edit: He could be Doctor Leonid Gakumba. Just a thought. You did have to assassinate him, he could have survived.

Comment: When you hover over the "conflict diamond" loot item, it mentions that it came from Bowa-Seko as well.

Answer (score 2):

Longinus was apparently baptized in the waters of [Goka Falls](http://farcry.wikia.com/wiki/Goka_Falls), the same place Leon was to be killed. So it is very likely that they could be the same person.

Comment: Hey MoonzWolf, your last sentence was more of a comment, so I removed it. (I also added a link to Goka Falls :))